# SAXNotRecognizedException when adding project to weblogic through eclipse

Tags: java, xml, exception, sax, xerces

We have a maven project which successfully builds when we do it from CLI.

Unfortunately when we try to add the project on weblogic through eclipse the following exception is thrown:

> 18-05-23 10:27:35 ERROR digester.Digester - Digester.getParser: 
>   org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException:
>   http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/dynamic     at
>   oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory.setFeature(JXSAXParserFactory.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.digester.parser.XercesParser.configureXerces(XercesParser.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.digester.parser.XercesParser.newSAXParser(XercesParser.java:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.digester.ParserFeatureSetterFactory.newSAXParser(ParserFeatureSetterFactory.java:71)

We have the following as a dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any suggestion on how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If it successfully builds from Maven, but does not work in Eclipse, it must be a difference in the JDK being used or the classpath.

My guess is that you have more than one XML library on your classpath and, due to the ordering of the classpath, a different one is taking precedence in each case.

To list the classpath in Maven:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=cp.txt
```

Manually compare the ordering with the Eclipse one (in the `.classpath` file), paying particular attention to any JARs that may contain XML libraries. If any JARs are missing or in a different order, adjust them to match the Maven classpath.

Comment: this error might also pop up for legacy projects that do not use Maven - in my case and according to this answer, there must have been a conflict with XercesImpl library we were including with the project - for sure there must have been another SAX parser implementation somewhere in the servlet container we were using. - so removing our XercesImpl from the deployment seemed to solve the issue.